# Copy all dependencies in a gradle project using java-library plugin

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies

Is there a way to copy all (including transitive) dependencies (jars) of a gradle project that uses **java-library** plugin to some folder, using a gradle task?

I can list all jars from the compileClasspath, but that does not seem to include [all] transitive dependencies.

```
task copyDependencies(type: Copy) {
   into "${rootProject.buildDir}/dependencies"
   from project.configurations.compileClasspath
}
```

Comment: I went and tried your task using Guava as a dependency (which, according to Gradle, has 5 transitive dependencies). The result was Guava and all the transitive dependencies being copied to the destination. What version of Gradle are you using? I tried this with Gradle 4.9.

Comment: Please add context to your question, what you did should just work. But to confirm, there needs to be a sample dependency declaration and any modifications to the `configuration` or `resolutionStrategy`.

Comment: Yes, it actually seems to work... or at least almost; I got the missing libraries by using `project.configurations.runtimeClasspath` instead of `project.configurations.compileClasspath`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code I posted actually seems to work... or at least almost; I got the missing libraries by using `project.configurations.runtimeClasspath` instead of `project.configurations.compileClasspath`